# How retrieve windows username in Oracle APEX 5?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I’m trying to retrieve windows username in Oracle APEX 5

How can I do this?

Please, help.

Comment: Please, avoid "how can i do X?" questions. Please show your work and the problems / errors you're having.

Comment: Do you want the Windows account on the client side or the database server?

Comment: Web browsers will generally not give out personal information (including logon names) to web sites. (Plus the browser may not be operating on a device that even has the concept of a user). Depending on your requirement, you might be able to use client ip address and map that to an individual.

Comment: On client side.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
select osuser 
from v$session
where sid = syscontext('USERENV','SID')
```

the caller would need read access to v$session

Comment: I mean that it returns nothing when client uses apex application. And usually v_$session/v$session is not able to APEX ANONYMOUS user (I granted select to this view).

Comment: I mean that it returns nothing when client uses apex application. And v_$session/v$session is not able to APEX ANONYMOUS user (I granted select to this view, but it’s not helped). Select sys_context(‘userenv’,’os_user’) from dual not working also (returns null) under APEX 5

Comment: This is a web client so the "osuser" will be the same for all client sessions. BTW it's `sys_context` :)